# In Clojure, how to change (def) a variable value inside a function

Tags: clojure

So, I've just started learning Clojure and I'm now facing a problem that I couldn't google myself out of.

Here is my code atm:

```
=> (def a "asd")
=> a
"asd"
=> (defn bla [entry_value] (def entry_value "qwe"))
=> (bla a)
#'exercise.core/entry_value
=> a
"asd"
=> entry_value
"qwe"
```

What I really wanted was for **a** to have **"qwe"** as value.
Is it possible?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A `var` is the wrong tool for this job. Use an `atom` instead. Thus, `(def a (atom "asd"))`, and `(defn bla [var] (reset! var "qwe"))`

Comment: ...so, an answer that tells you how to pass a reference to the var itself is *possible*, but it would be advising you to write bad-practice code. If you want to know how to do it as an exercise, that's one thing, but if this is a pattern you'd follow in real code, don't.

Comment: I've just changed my question because I didn't know "var" was a reserved word. My bad.

Comment: A `var` is the kind of thing that `def` makes -- so even with that variable name updated, you're still trying to write a function that redefines a var, which is inside the set of things-that-idiomatic-code-doesn't-do (for good reasons -- updating a var involves locking, f/e, and some compile-time optimizations make it literally impossible; atoms have much more sensible performance guarantees).

Comment: What you're doing is called a side effect, and in functional languages you should try to avoid side effects. Returning the new value from the function is more idiomatic. It is a common mistake when coming from imperative paradigms.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and m0skit0 so I actually shouldn't be trying to do that in clojure, right? I should do it differently...

Comment: @GuiFGDeo, ...right -- if you want to rebind a value that's referred to by a var in-place, use an `atom`, as I showed you in the very first comment... but try to separate the logic that *calculates* the new value from the code that *assigns* the value; better to have a `(defn my-func [old-value] "qwe")` and call `(swap! a my-func)` instead of calling `(my-func a)` (if `a` is an atom).

Comment: All right, thank you @CharlesDuffy for the input, I will change that in my code!

Comment: @m0skit0 what if I want to return 2 values from one function? is it possible/idiomatic?

Comment: @GuiFGDeo, ...typically that means one returns a data type that incorporates both those values.

Comment: The key concepts about Clojure are functional and immutability. If you follow those you will be idiomatic most of the time :)

Comment: I don't know if commenting here would be the best option, but how would you "remove something from a vector" idiomatically? I can only do that by "DEFing" the vector again and using (remove #{} ...) to remove the desired value. But then maybe I shouldn't be using vectors like that in the first place...

Comment: @GuiFGDeo I totally agree with you. You should return a new vector, not mutably modify the vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, technically it is possible with the help of [alter-var-root](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/alter-var-root) function like this

```
=> (defn bla [entry-value] (alter-var-root entry-value (fn [_] "qwe")))
=> #'user/bla
=> (def a "asd")
=> #'user/a
=> (bla #'a)
=> "qwe"
=> a
=> "qwe"
```

But this is not how Vars (things definded with `def`) are supposed to work in Clojure. `def` is used to declare a *binding* in Clojure, not a *variable*. *Binding* means that you bind some value to some name and it does not change in the future e.g. that binding is immutable. Other functions in your program may relay on that immutability, so please do not use `alter-var-root` or other methods of changing bindings in your code.

If you really need some kind of variable with mutable state - please use `atoms`.

I would encourage you to read ["Clojure for brave and true"](https://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/) which contains very good and concise explanations on the topic.

About `def` [here](https://www.braveclojure.com/do-things/) under "Naming values with Def" section.

Atoms, Vars and state management are discussed [here](https://www.braveclojure.com/zombie-metaphysics/).

P.S. You can test the code above using [this online repl](https://repl.it/@achikin/Changing-Var-in-clojure).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation Anton. I will indeed look through your links! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Also if the *var* in question has been previously `def` (declared) `dynamic` you could make it to get, let's say [temporally | keeping immutability] rendered with new values as following:
Edit: References for example [here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding#example-542692d2c026201cdc326f54)

```
(def ^:dynamic x 5) ;; =>#'user/x
(def ^:dynamic y 3) ;; =>#'user/y
x                                       ;=> 5
y                                       ;=> 3

(binding [x 2 y 7] (+ x y))             ;=> 9
(+ x y)                                 ;=> 8

(defn add-val [] (+ x y))               ;=>#'user/add-val
(binding [x 3 y 7] (add-val))           ;=> 10
(+ x y)                                 ;=> 8 x y still immutable values
```

Answer (score 0):

With functions this does not work. Functions work this way that when you call them, the arguments are evaluated before entering the function. That means if you call `(bla a)`, the first what happens is that the string "a" is replaced by the contents of `a`. Your call is actually `(bla "asd")`. The name of the variable is gone. So functions do not help you.

You can workaround this if you pass something else that is not evaluated. This can be either a string or something what Anton Chikin proposes. But such solution will always be a syntanctic compromise.

What you probably want is a macro. In macros arguments are not evaluated. This is what macros are made for.

You have two option to achieve this.

```
(defmacro bla [entry_value] `(def ~entry_value "qwe"))
```

or

```
(defmacro bla [entry_value] (list 'def entry_value "qwe"))
```

You see what it does with `(macroexpand-1 '(bla a))`

The benefit, however, is limited. This is not dynamic behaviour. The macro is just a syntax shortcut. You may want to to do something like
`(let [var a] (bla var))` or `(let [var 'a] (bla var))`. But this does not work with macros. You may see already the problem. When typing this, things get already evaluated and the macro is also evaluated immediately.

What also does not work is changing `a` from outside the namespace.

But it is still a good exercise for writing macros.